# Generating random color in Unity isn't working properly

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

So i have a very strange bug i think.. I have a script where i generate a random color and assign it to the player, the thing is that the color is always white but when i look to the color panel in inspector it is showing a normal random color.Another fun thing is that when i change the color in inspector in play mode it actually changes[image]

```
    float R = Random.Range(0, 226);
    float G = Random.Range(0, 226);
    float B = Random.Range(0, 226);
    ColorToBeGenerate = new Color(R, G, B);
    Player.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().color = ColorToBeGenerate;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit:**

`Color` constructor takes float values from 0 to 1 .. not int between 0 to 255. as **derHuge** Mentioned

change your code as following

```
float R = Random.Range(0, 226/255f);
float G = Random.Range(0, 226/255f);
float B = Random.Range(0, 226/255f);
ColorToBeGenerate = new Color(R, G, B);
Player.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().color = ColorToBeGenerate;
```

Answer (score 1):

The actual reason is: [`Color`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Color-ctor.html) constructor takes **float** values from `0` to `1` .. not int between 0 to 255. So your random values between `0` and `225` (the 226 is exclusive) will be clamped to `1` so it is most likely (with a chance of 225 to 1) that the result will always be `1` or in the other case `0`. -> Color will always result in white.

So yes you either have to change it to values between `0` and `1` like in the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64957826/7111561)

or alternatively use [`Color32`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Color32.html) with int values between `0` and `255` like

```
int R = Random.Range(0, 227);
int G = Random.Range(0, 227);
int B = Random.Range(0, 227);
ColorToBeGenerate = new Color32(R, G, B, 255);
Player.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().color = ColorToBeGenerate;
```

`Color32` can be implicitly converted to `Color` and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar bug a while ago.
Using a `Color32` instead of a `Color` fixed it for me.

Comment: It worked but i can't inseart int or float variables to make it random, i realised another thing that only the yellow color is visible, any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

public Color color;
color = new Color(Random.value,Random.value, Random.value, 1.0f);
alpha argument is there

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).